# iojs/electron - Output all in console to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm currently building an application in Electron which is at the moment using iojs 2.3.1, and what I'd like to do is output anything and everything that prints out in the dev tools console to file.

In the earlier versions of node this used to be available by piping from stdout/stderr, this is no longer possible and I can't for the life of me find a solution that works and doesn't involve changing large amounts of code.

Does anyone have a working solution for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

End working result was using Winston with a quick change to make it work with Electron. https://github.com/dustinblackman/winston

EDIT:

As this answer is still being viewed, this solution is better. https://github.com/dustinblackman/winston-electron

Comment: Could you elaborate on the changes you had to make to get this to work?

Comment: Changes can be found here. https://github.com/dustinblackman/winston/commit/6564d7cb8f2403f43a14c8e0ffd2a18058cea195

Essentially, it checks to see if the electron version exists in `process.version`. If it does, it uses electrons `console` methods, otherwise it writes to `stdout` or `stderr`. Pretty simple patch.

Comment: You can also define winston in the main process and use it from renderer via the shared objects

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom console like so:

```
var output = fs.createWriteStream('./stdout.log');
var errorOutput = fs.createWriteStream('./stderr.log');
// custom simple logger
var logger = new Console(output, errorOutput);
// use it like console
var count = 5;
logger.log('count: %d', count);
// in stdout.log: count 5
```

See https://iojs.org/api/console.html#console_new_console_stdout_stderr

---

Apparently exceptions do not print to the error log, this is a workaround:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  logger.error('Caught exception: ' + err);
});
```

Comment: Ah that's awesome!  And what about exceptions? It's to be used the most on other users machines where I can't recreate an issue. That's why everything.

Comment: @Dustin I just played around with it and doesn't seem like it does. P̶e̶r̶h̶a̶p̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶'̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶a̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶v̶i̶a̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶c̶e̶s̶s̶.̶o̶n̶(̶'̶u̶n̶c̶a̶u̶g̶h̶t̶E̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶'̶)̶?̶ ̶W̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶p̶l̶a̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶.̶ There is a workaround. See edit